# SQL Server 2008 R2 login not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have just installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio. But I do not know what is the default login.

I searched over internet for solution, but no luck!

I have tried following solutions:

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server Name: `.`
- Authentication: Windows Authentication

and

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server Name: `.\SqlExpress`
- Authentication: Windows Authentication

But not sure why not working, I keep getting the following error:

> Connect to Server
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
>   Provider, error: 0 - The message received was unexpected or badly
>   formatted.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893018)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default login for windows authentication. I believe you need to add the current user as an administrator to login. Did you select SQL and Windows authentication and provide an SA password?

Comment: Can you post any code if applicable of how you are connecting ?

Comment: I have installed Sql Server Management Studio 2008 R2. 
My OS is windows 8.1
I have already installed Visual Sudio 20013 and 2015.
I do not know whats going on, why i can not use the sql server management studio.
Whats going on with my machine.
I am sick of all this crap :(

Answer (score 0):

OP, has your computer had any recent updates? The SQL services tend to stop when system receives big updates, check that there are no services stopped.

[image: Sql Services]

The only reason I'm assuming this is your solution is because I see you can't even log in with Windows Authentication

Comment: I can not see the above services installed on my machine. 
Can you please give me the links and process for how to install the SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have only installed SQL Management Studio and not SQL Server with Tools i.e. SQL Server plus SSMS. I guess this is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have only installed SQL Management Studio and not SQL Server with Tools i.e. SQL Server plus SSMS. I guess this is what you need? Also there is nothing wrong with your machine it is just that you require an instance of sql and you have only installed the management studio so you now just need to install sql server 2008 R2 express (FREE) I would suggest.